# Optional Argument for Function in Python

Tags: python, arguments, option-type

If i try to give a function an optional argument, this way it won't work:

```
def speed(self, max, now):
    self.min = 0
    self.max = max
    if now != None:
        self.now = now
    else:
        self.now = 0
    return self.max, self.now
```

Can someone help me to understand this and how to do it better?
Do i really need the if statement? Maybe there is an easier and faster way with some kind of special argument?

Comment: It's in a very early step of the official tutorial: [Default Argument Values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [default argument value](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) to set `now` to `0` when omitted:

```
def speed(self, max, now=0):
    self.min = 0
    self.max = max
    self.now = now
    return self.max, self.now
```

Now the caller can simply omit specifying a value for the `now` argument:

```
some_instance.speed(42)
```

would leave `now` set to `0`.